# Chinese font with no smoothing got set as default after installing Chinese Languge Support (how to disable it?)

Tags: fonts, chinese

**Before:**

[image]

**After:**

[image]

I suspect this is the undesired font:

[image]

EDIT: I think is this font: **AR PL UMing TW**.

Is there a way of removing it or giving preference to another Chinese font?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the default UI font in System » Preferences » Appearence » Fonts.

If the default Chinese font when installing the Chinese Language Support is not good enough, you can report it so that the font gets replaced.

Comment: @user4124 would they take consideration of my opinion?

Answer (score 0):

The best fonts for Traditional Chinese is "Source Han Sans"(Noto Sans CJK), I suggest you to download the latest version in the official website, the system fonts should be remain as default, because it is way too ugly to use a Chinese font for English.

fonts: https://www.google.com/get/noto/

config file: https://mega.nz/#!qBQwjQiC!_CC5ce3fczgzJeg3lHy9gaoOe3rp7eWjJyXPe7h-mcE

How to install:

> 1. Download the fonts and config file above
> 2. Create a folder called "Noto" in "/usr/share/fonts/"
> 3. Unzip the fonts into that folder, and put the config file into "/etc/fonts/"

That's it.